# Encrypt nodejs data to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, cryptography

I'm currently using Crypto to encrypt/ decrypt data, but, if the server restarts, the decrypt won't work anymore. That's what i'm currently using =>

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const algorithm = "aes-256-cbc"; 
const initVector = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const Securitykey = crypto.randomBytes(32);

function encrypt(text){
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector);
    let encryptedData = cipher.update(text, "utf-8", "hex");
    encryptedData += cipher.final("hex");
    return encryptedData;
}

function decrypt(text){
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector);
    let decryptedData = decipher.update(text, "hex", "utf-8");
    decryptedData += decipher.final("utf8");
    return decryptedData;
}
```

And this is the error I get if i want to decrypt something after server restart

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Comment: You create a random key and a random IV at the beginning. Are these data stored somewhere, so that they are available again after the restart of the server? If not, key and IV of the decryption do not match those of the encryption.

Comment: @Topaco make it an answer.

Comment: i see. thank you too for the answer. I did how @Jay Godhani answered, and now i got an error => TypeError: Invalid initialization vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I can see from the code your IV and Key are randomly generated and I am assuming that you are not saving them anywhere.

```
const initVector = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const Securitykey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
```

So basically on server restart you are getting a new pair of IV and key, so when you are decrypting it is not matching with the Key and IV used at the time of encryption.

My suggested solution :

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const algorithm = "aes-256-cbc"; 
const initVectorString = "Any random hex string of 16bytes"; // You can store this into a env file
const SecuritykeyString = "Random security hex string of 32bytes"; // You can store this into a env file
const initVector = Buffer.from(initVectorString, "hex");  
const Securitykey = Buffer.from(SecurityKeyString, "hex");

function encrypt(text){
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector);
    let encryptedData = cipher.update(text, "utf-8", "hex");
    encryptedData += cipher.final("hex");
    return encryptedData;
}

function decrypt(text){
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector);
    let decryptedData = decipher.update(text, "hex", "utf-8");
    decryptedData += decipher.final("utf8");
    return decryptedData;
}
```

Update:-

So if you are using a utf-8 string for IV then the string length should be 16 characters only (if you are using only 1 byte characters a-zA-Z0-9 all are 1 byte characters) and you need to change the encoding type in Buffer.from() function from "Hex" to "utf-8".

Similar for the security key length of the string should be 32 characters only and you need to change the encoding type in Buffer.from() function from "Hex" to "utf-8".

Comment: now i get an error => TypeError: Invalid initialization vector

Comment: Can you share your IV and Key pair ? Probably you are getting "Error: Invalid IV length" error, if not then can you share the whole error log ?

Comment: @LupuCl Sorry it was my mistake I forgot to mention some key points. I have updated my answer kindly go through it, I hope it will solve your error.

Comment: const initVectorString = '1234567890zxcvbn';
const SecuritykeyString = '1234567890zxcvbn1234567890zxcvbn';
const initVector = Buffer.from(initVectorString, 'hex');  
const Securitykey = Buffer.from(SecuritykeyString, 'hex');

That's what i currently have, and still get this error..

Comment: Oh, i forgot to change the encoding in buffer to utf-8. Works now, thank you so much!!!